Using git bash "find" and "sed" correctly. Do I have the best solution?
I am using git bash on Windows.
I have a large set (thousands) of c/c++ files with autogenerated headers that I want to replace.  My plan is first to strip the headers then apply new ones.
These headers follow the pattern:
/************************************************************************************ ///_|
File: $Id: //perforcedepot/path/filename.ext#1 $

LEGAL NOTICE: COPYRIGHT YYYY by COMPANY NAME, All Rights Reserved 
*************************************************************************************/ //|_/

I experimented a bit and came up with this:
sed '/\/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/,/\/ \/\/\|\_\//d' filename.ext

Seems good enough, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do the match?
Also, I tested it with find as so:
find . -iregex '.*\.\(h\|c\|hpp\|cpp\)$' -exec sed '/\/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/,/\/ \/\/\|\_\//d' {} \;

Seems to be picking up the correct files, based on a small test sample.
My plan is now to add "-i" to make sed overwrite the files.
But I feel like I made this harder on myself than it needed to be.  So my question is:  Did I come by the right approach here?  Is there an easier solution?

One of the reasons listed for closing a question is that it's Opinion Based so YMMV specifically asking for our opinion - "Do I have the best solution?".

perhaps something like sed -E '\@/\*{84} /{3}_\|@d'

If you can rely on your /***... beginning to be at the first position in the line, you can use the RE anchor to only  scan at the front of the line, i.e. @^/\*\*.....@ and similar to anchor for the end of the line (again assuming no trainling spaces or tabs) @/ //\|_/$@. The ^ and $ anchor searches to the front and end of the line, respectively.  Doesn't your auto-generation tool have a way of overwriting /deleting existing? Good luck.

please clarify: when you say "header" do you mean that it is a set of lines that appears at the start of the file, before everything else? Is it always precisely 5 lines, with 2nd starting File: $Id: and 4th starting LEGAL NOTICE ?

To answer shellter, the auto-generation tool is lost.  This is a very old codebase.  To jhnc, the header is unfortunately not always at the top of the file.

This might work for you (GNU sed & find):
find . -iregex ".*/.*\(h\|c\|hpp\|cpp\)$" \
       -exec sed  -Ei '\#^/\*+ ///_\|$#,\#^\*+/ //\|_/$#d' {} +

In the sed command turn on extended regexp's and modify file in place options.
Use a range to delete the headers, however to make things a little easier on the eye (perhaps?) use alternative delimiters i.e. \#...#,\#...#.
N.B. End the exec command with + as this is probably more  efficient.

Thank you, but the "find" command is returning .inc files as well as the expected files.  I think maybe it should be: find . -iregex ".*.(h|c|hpp|cpp)$" | less
